# Will my MP stats from the AC:R beta carry over to the Revelations Multiplayer?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I want to buy Assassin's Creed Revelations, and I participated in the beta gaining experience and leveling my avatar up to level 30 (the beta limit). If I buy the full game, will my stats (like XP, weapons, skins, etc.) carry over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will start from scratch again but you will level up quite quickly having the play experience from the beta.